# SAP HANA SQL in calculated column

Tags: sql, calculated-columns, hana

What are the exact possibilities for Calculated Columns in SAP HANA?

I have often trouble building calculated columns - even though using SQL (not column engine)

So I have to use `concat(col1, col2)` instead of `col1 || col2`

**Now I want to do:**

the equivalent of ABAP `CONDENSE( COL1 )`

HANA SQL : `replace_regexpr ( '[[:space:]]+' 
                        IN  COL1
                        WITH ' ')`

**How to do it in a calculated column?**

Comment: I don't use HANA, but I believe you need to include `OCCURRENCE ALL` after your `WITH ' '` in that `replace_regexpr()` formula to insure that all occurences of `[[:space:]]+` are matched. And that `COL1` you may want to wrap in `TRIM()` to knock off the leading and ending whitespace before `replace_regexpr()` gets it's hand on it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the graphical modeller supports only the functions listed in the *Function* window of the *Expression Editor*. However, if you create a [scripted calculation view](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/09/01/sap-hana-scripted-calculation-view-part-1/) you will be able to active the following code:

```sql
/********* Begin Procedure Script ************/ 
BEGIN 
   var_out = select REPLACE_REGEXPR('[[:space:]]+' in "<YOUR_COLUMN>" with ' ') as "CONDENSED_TEXT" from "<YOUR_SCHEMA>"."<YOUR_TABLE>";

END /********* End Procedure Script ************/
```

The use of [Table Functions in Calculation views](http://teachmehana.com/sap-hana-table-function-calculation-view-2/) could be another possibility.